# ts-expect-error only for a certain type of error

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to make `//ts-expect-error` directive only cover a concrete error and not others?

Example of code I would like to silent but only for some kind of error:

[image]

Error TS2588
[image]

Error TS2339
[image]

I would expect something like ESLint does with rules: `//@ts-expect-error TS2339` to only silent errors of that kind, for example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not currently possible - this has been a [long standing request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19139); one of the underlying issues is that the error codes are moving targets, as they're not meant to be used for explicit referencing.

Comment: I wonder if there's been any update